# Automatic inheritance for django models

Tags: python, django, database, inheritance

I have a django project which has models like this.

```
class Part(models.Model):
  attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Document(models.Model):
  part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
  attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and so on.
There are a lot of models in one single module and I need for each model a separate model with the same attributes plus one or more additional attributes.
How would I do that without writing every single class by hand?

**Edit**
Ok the question was a little unclear.
I want to have 2 separate table in the database for each model one as it is written above and one with an additional column.

**Edit 2**
I think I got it, when I put

```
import inspect
import sys

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, models.Model) and hasattr(obj, 'Meta') and inspect.isclass(obj.Meta) and not (
                hasattr(obj.Meta, 'abstract') and obj.Meta.abstract):
        globals()["Edit" + name] = type("Edit" + name, (obj,), {'fu': 'bar'})
```

at the bottom of my models.py, I get a new model for each model defined in in this file.
So I would get `EditPart` and `EditDocument` classes each with an attribute `fu`.

Comment: Is it okay to put minimal effort into asking and expect others to do the research and try for me and feed me the answer with on a gold platter?

Answer (score 0):

How about an [abstract model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) from which you can inherit?

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Part(BaseModel):
    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Document(BaseModel):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, although I see that my question was a little unclear. I want a model Part and a model somethingPart where the somethingPart is the same as Part but has a additional attribute.

Comment: Can you not use an abstract model to do that?